# Rotate and crop image using canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have web application which can upload images to server.
I want to crop and rotate image before sent to server.
Any way to do this using HTML 5 Canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, html canvas can crop and rotate an image.

**Crop:** Use the extended properties of context.drawImage.

```
context.drawImage(img,cropX,cropY,cropWidth,cropHeight,0,0,cropWidth,cropHeight);
```

**Rotate:** Use the context.rotate property.

```
// set the point of rotation (example below sets rotation point at center-image)

context.translate(img.width/2,img.height/2);

// do the rotation (in radians)

context.rotate(radianAngle);
```

Note: all transforms (translate,rotate,etc) are cumulative unless you context.save/context.restore.